# Protractor - working with rows from by.repeater... can't get column() to work

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e

Why does this work...

```
  this.modelChoices = function(rowNumber) {
    return element.all(by.repeater('model in vehicleCheckboxes.models')).get(0).isSelected();
  } 

   it('all models should be deselected', function() {
    expect(ppvPercentages.modelChoices()).to.eventually.be.false;
  });
```

but not this?

```
  this.modelChoices = function(rowNumber) {
    return element.all(by.repeater('model in vehicleCheckboxes.models').row(0).column('model.description').isSelected();
```

or this?

```
  this.modelChoices = function(rowNumber) {
    return element.all(by.repeater('model in vehicleCheckboxes.models').row(0)).isSelected();
  }
```

Comment: I think you should not be using `row()` and `column()` - it is a part of an old API and I am not sure it is being supported and actively developed.

Comment: Oh wow...ok. It is still fresh in protractor documentation examples for `by.repeater` http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater